# C++ Borland char * and strcpy

Tags: c++, c++builder, strcpy

```
char *dum[32];
strcpy(&dum,InstList->Lines->Text.c_str());
```

`InstList` is a `TMemo` of C++ Builder

Why am I getting this error?

> > [C++ Error] emulator.cpp(59): E2034 Cannot convert 'char * *' to 'char *'
> >       Full parser context
> >         emulator.cpp(56): parsing: void _fastcall TMain::Button1Click(TObject *)

Answer (score 2):

```
char *dum[32];
```

is an array of length 32, each element being a `char*`.  I guess you meant to write

```
char dum[32];
```

This is an array of 32 char and you can then write:

```
strcpy(dum, InstList->Lines->Text.c_str());
```

Make sure, of course, `InstList->Lines->Text` is not so big that it overflows your buffer.

Of course, I'm not sure why you would need to use C strings in a C++ program.

Answer (score 2):

You either use (prone to serious security problem called *buffer overflow*)

```
char dum[32];
strcpy(dum,InstList->Lines->Text.c_str());
```

OR (much better since it works with any length without being prone to a serious security problem called *buffer overflow*)

```
// C style
// char *dum = malloc(strlen(InstList->Lines->Text.c_str())+1); 

// BCB style...
char *dum = malloc(InstList->Lines->Text.Length()+1);  

// BEWARE: AFTER any malloc you should check the pointer returned for being NULL

strcpy(dum,InstList->Lines->Text.c_str());
```

**EDIT - as per comments:**

I am assuming that you are using an older BCB version which still has `AnsiString` - if this is on a newer version `UnicodeString` then the code could lead to "strange results" since unicode string take up multiple bytes per character (depending on the encoding etc.).

Comment: Good points, but no need even to use `strlen` since `InstList->Lines->Text` comes with a length property for sure. Not sure on the C++ Builder syntax mind you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Last time I used C++ Builder is several years ago... looked it up...

Comment: According to the docs, `Text` is `System::UnicodeString` and you would write `Length(System::UnicodeString)` from Delphi, I assume that C++ Builder is the same. `Text` is dynamically generated from the contents of the Windows EDIT control that is behind the TMemo. I'd probably read it out into a `System::UnicodeString` variable first. One can only wonder where C strings come into the equation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you are right for the current versions... but for example C++ Builder 6(!) has this as `AnsiString` defined... unbelievable but V 6 is still in use... when I saw the C string handling I thought of the old versions, otherwise this code would do no good...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan checked the docs... `System::UnicodeString` would return `wchar_t *` as a result of `c_str()`... given the error message the OP posted this seems to be an older version with `AnsiString`...

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I didn't know you could do `::Length()` and `::c_str()` on a C++Builder `AnsiString` or indeed `UnicodeString`. None of that available for us Delphi users! There were would write `Length(str)` and `PChar(str)`. Anyway, I think we've got this Q covered.

Answer (score 1):

```
char dum[32];   
strcpy(dum,InstList->Lines->Text.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `char*` use `String` or `std::string` instead and if you need a pointer to your string for some reason just take this from your string object.

```
String myString = InstList->Lines->Text;
myString.c_str();
```